# How to find the region of pre-images of a complex function?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

> How to find domain of a complex function?

For example, say a function $f(z) = z^2$ maps a region $D$ of complex plane to a region $R$ which is a disc of radius $4$ and centre $4 + 0 i$, then, how can I find the region $D$?

My background: I am not familiar with the properties of complex function and calculus relevant to that, so I can't attempt that.

Though, I tried following things:

I took some simple number like $4 + 0i , 2 + 0i , 8 + 0i$ and applied $f^{-1} (z)$ , I found the domain $D$ has not circular boundary because the scaling factor for any number $z$ is not fixed.

I thought it is something parametrised region like in multivariable calculus, but couldn't come with something good, because I can't account for the rotation factor which is in complex number geometry.

Comment: I friendly reference for high-school student for complex analysis is also requested.

Comment: I tried that, shifted the origin to $z_0$ (Centre) then?

Comment: You may consult "Visual Complex Analysis" by Tristan Needham, or; if you have advanced to a certain level, the wonderful book by Joseph Bak and Donald Newman

Comment: Yeah, reading introduction to differentiations and amplitwist concept.

Comment: Required region is lemniscate or cassinian curve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$D=\{z:z^{2}\in R\}=\{z:|z^{2}-4|<4$. Writing real and imaginary parts of $z$ as $x$ and $y$ we have have to find all $z$ such that $|x^{2}-y^{2}+2ixy-4|^{2} <16$ which reduces to $ (x^{2}-y^{2}-4)^{2}+4x^{2}y^{2} <16$ or $(x^{2}-y^{2})^{2}-8(x^{2}-y^{2})+4x^{2}y^{2}<0$. You can write this as $ (x^{2}+y^{2})^{2} <8(x^{2}-y^{2})$. I don't think this can be further simplified.